# How is the function "determinant" well-defined and where is recursion theorem used?

Tags: linear-algebra

Let's first denote $\overline{A}_{1j}$ to be a matrix where first row and $j$-th column are removed from $A$.

Definition of determinant, as usual, is: $\det(A)=\sum_{j=1}^n (-1)^{1+j} A_{1j} \det(\overline{A}_{1j})$.

How is this defined *recursively*?

Let $f(1)$ be a function from $M_{1\times 1}$ to $F$ such that $f(1)(A)=A_{11}$ ($F$ is a field).

To apply recursion theorem, we need a function $\gamma$ such that $f(n+1)=\gamma(f(n))$. However, we cannot apply this.

Let $A\in M_{{n+1}\times{n+1}}$.

Then $f(n+1)(A)=\sum_{j=1}^{n+1} (-1)^{1+j} A_{1j} f(n)(\overline{A}_{1j})$ in order to satisfy my goal.

However, this cannot be simply represented as $f(n+1)(A)=\gamma(f(n))(A)$ for some function $\gamma$.

How is the function *determinant* well-defined?

Comment: There is not one recursively defined determinant function. There is a family of determinant functions $\det_n:M_{n,n}(K)\to K$, indexed by $n\in\mathbf N$, and one can define $\det_{n+1}$ in terms of $\det_n$. This is not the setting of the [recursion theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursion#The_recursion_theorem) which defines function $\mathbf N\to X$. What's the problem?

Comment: @Marc As you said, i wanted to apply the recursion theorem on a function from a function space and i had a problem how to define a necessary function. I see $f(n)$ defined in my argument below is $\det_n$ in your comment. Thank you

Comment: However there is no function space $Y^X$ that contains functions $M_{n,n}(K)\to K$ for _all $n\in\mathbf N$ at once_.

Comment: @Marc You are right, but it is provable that if there are countable functions $\gamma_n:A\rightarrow A$ and $f(n+1)=\gamma_n(f(n))$, then $f:A\rightarrow A$ is well-defined.

Answer (score 1):

You are right, we cannot represent $f=\det$ as $f(n+1)(A)=\gamma(f(n))(A)$. 
Here $f(n)$ is a **function** on $M_{n\times n}$ therefore $f(n+1)(A)=\gamma(f(n))(A)$ does not "make sense" because $A$ cannot be in the domain of both $f(n+1)$ and $\gamma(f(n))$.

Answer (score 0):

Let ${\beta_j}^{(n+1)}:M_{(n+1)\times(n+1)}\rightarrow M_{n\times n}$ be a function which removes first row and $j$-th column.

Then $\forall (n\in\mathbb{Z}^+ \bigwedge 1≦j≦n+1), {\beta_j}^{(n+1)}$ is well defined.

Now, define $\gamma_n$ as follows:

$(\gamma_n(g))(A)=\sum_{j=1}^n (-1)^{1+j} A_{1j} g({\beta_j}^(n+1))(A)$ for all $A,g$ in its natural domain.

Then, $\gamma_n$ is well defined for $n\in\mathbb{Z}^+$.

Then $f(n+1)=\gamma_n(f(n))$.

Comment: So, at the end of the day, what are the domains and codomains of the $\gamma_n$? Where does $f$ live?

Comment: @Branimir $\gamma_n:F^{M_{n\times n}} \rightarrow F^{M_{(n+1)\times (n+1)}}$ and $f(n):M_{n\times n} \rightarrow F$.

Comment: OK. I guess I'm just not seeing what just what the original worry was with defining $\det_{n+1} : M_{n+1}(F) \to F$ inductively in terms of $\det_n : M_n(F) \to F$, given the base case $\det_1 : M_1(F) \to F$, $\det_1 : (a) \mapsto a$.

Comment: @Branimir I had a trouble how to take appropriate $\gamma_n$. By the way, is my argument correct? I'm not really sure if it is right or wrong.

Comment: I'm afraid I'm a complete layman when it comes to matters set-theoretical or foundational! From what I can gather, everything looks correct, though you'd know better than I do if everything is primed for applying the recursion theorem, and how.